# What is kabolas ponim on a wedding

Tags: halacha, minhag, marriage

I understand that the groom has kabolas ponim before the bedekin

And the bride when she comes to the hupa (by said Boruch habo)

Is this correct? 
what is the requirements of the kabolas ponim? (Minimum and complete)
 Sources on subject please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no Halachic requirement for a Kabolas Ponim at a wedding.

Regarding the groom, sometimes it's used as a Jewish way of referring to the optional pre-Chuppa smorgasbord.

Sometimes Kabolas Ponim refers to the ceremony of the groom signing the Ketuba before the wedding. Others called this the Chosson-Tisch.

All the above are optional, and many a Kosher wedding officially  started at the Bedekin.

Regarding the bride, there's a custom by some that the groom steps forwardt to *greet* the bride as she approaches the Chuppa. I guess it could be called a Kabolas Ponim. The Kitzur Shulchan Aruch in [סימן קמז - מנהגי החפה](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_00561.html#HtmpReportNum0146_L2) describes it such:

> **סעיף ה'**:
>   אַחַר כָּךְ מוֹלִיכִין אֶת הֶחָתָן תַּחַת הַחֻפָּה, (שֶׁפּוֹרְסִין יְרִיעָה עַל גַּבֵּי כְּלוֹנְסָאוֹת, שֶׁאָנוּ קוֹרִין חֻפָּה), וּמַעֲמִידִין אוֹתוֹ פָּנָיו לַמִּזְרָח, וּשְּׁלִיחַ הַצִּבּוּר מְנַגֵּןכְּמִנְהַג הַמָּקוֹם, וְהַשּׁוֹשְׁבִינוֹת מוֹלִיכוֹת אֶת הַכַּלָּה, **וְהַֹשּׁוֹשְׁבִינִים וַאֲנָֹשִים חֲֹשוּבִים הוֹלְכִים לִקְרָאתָהּ**. וּכְשֶׁמִּתְקָרְבִים אֵלֶיהָ, חוֹזְרִים לַאֲחוֹרֵיהֶם לַחֻפָּה, וְהַֹשּׁוֹשְׁבִינוֹת מְבִיאוֹת אֶת הַכַּלָּה וּמְסוֹבְבוֹת עִמָּהּ שֶׁבַע פְּעָמִים אֶת הֶחָתָן, וּשְּׁלִיחַ הַצִּבּוּר מְנַגֵּן גַּם כֵּן כְּפִי הַמִּנְהָג. אַחַר כָּךְ מַעֲמִידִין אֶת הַכַּלָּה לִימִין הֶחָתָן, וְהַמְבָרֵךְ מְצַדֵּד אֶת עַצְמוֹ וּפָנָיו לַמִּזְרָח. ‏

Comment: This is a thorough answer accounting for multiple nuances of the term. In breif, though, the term *kabalat panim* often appears on the wedding invitations, and tends to be 1 - 1.5 hours before the start of the chuppa. (Based on most of the invitations that I've been getting, recently.) It refers to the start time of the buffet / cocktail "hour / smorgasbord (whatever you want to call it.) The groom has his "tisch" in a separate room during that time, as mentioned, above.